# iOS: reroute system sound to earpiece (receiver)?

Tags: ios, system, audio, system-sounds

I'm adding a Voice Memo feature to my Enterprise app. I'm using the iPhone's Proximity Detector to start recording when the user lifts the phone to their face. The action also uses the System Sound (AudioToolbox) to play a "beep" sound to let the user know it's recording.

My problem is that the Beep plays through the lower speaker. I'd like to get it to play through the earpiece when the user raises the phone to their face, just like Siri does.

Since this is a recorder/playback functionality, I am mixing both SystemSound and an AVAudioSession in the same class. I know how to reroute the AVAudioSession to either the earpiece or the speaker, but I can't figure out how to do that with SystemSounds.

Any ideas?

Thanks!